# How can I different parameters using Criteria Restriction.like, Hibernate and Spring?

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate, criteria

I would like to know how to search the same parameter in different columns.

When I do "criteria.add(Restrictions.like("firstName", search + "%"));" it works, but just for a single column.

So, how can I use "OR" using Criteria?

```
    Criteria criteria = createEntityCriteria();

    if (search != null && !search.equals("")) {
        criteria.add(Restrictions.like("firstName || lastName || mobileNo || ssn", search + "%"));
        System.out.println("search " + search);
    }

    return (List<Employee>) criteria.list();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use like this for disjunction ;

```
criteria.add(Restrictions.disjunction()
      .add(Restrictions.like("firstName", search + "%"))
      .add(Restrictions.like("lastName", search + "%")) 
      .add(Restrictions.like("mobileNo", search + "%")) 
      .add(Restrictions.like("ssn", search + "%")));
```

- **Disjunction**  --> Group expressions together in a single disjunction (A or B or C...)
- **Conjuction**  --> Group expressions together in a single conjunction (A and B and C...)

Comment: thanks, it works with "disjunction" and also with "or".Have a nice day!

Answer (score 3):

Restrictions has an `or` method which accepts any number of Criterions, so you can do:

```
criteria.add(Restrictions.or(
    Restrictions.like("firstName", search + "%"),
    Restrictions.like("lastName", search + "%"),
    Restrictions.like("mobileNo", search + "%"),
    Restrictions.like("ssn", search + "%"))
);
```

Comment: thanks, it works without the second "Restiction.like". Have a nice day!

Comment: Whoops thanks, didn't mean to duplicate it - copy paste error! Updated my answer